# Why is the box with chat options not visible on the main site?

Tags: support, bug

I remember when I first joined this site, a box containing the active chat rooms would be visible on the right side of the home page of the site. However, currently all I can see is filters, tags and hot network questions:

[image: chemistry stackexchange main page]

Curiously, the box is visible on the meta site:

[image: meta home page]

Why is this the case? Is it only my browser, or is it an internal feature? The chat option should be more visible, and it's presence on the main page is more important than on meta imo.

I am using Mozilla Firefox on Windows 10.

Comment: Curious. I have not noticed. Have you checked [meta.se]?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127282/show-the-chat-box-in-the-sidebar-for-public-beta-sites) about beta sites. The answer says that the behaviour is different on different sites and is inconsistent. Do you see the chat box on the main page?

Comment: That's old; wouldn't surprise me if the whole code about this had changed. I don't see the chat, that may have different reasons … Let's just wait and see.

Comment: I agree that it changed some time ago. Just roll with it - I think it happened with the overhaul of the overall UI.

Comment: @JonCuster I feel that the chat should be visible on the main page, that's why I made the post. Should I add the feature request tag then?

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti - fair enough, but as a network-wide thing it should be asked on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ instead of here - we don't control the overall UI.

Comment: @JonCuster (and @ShoubhikRMaiti) you don't need to do that. As far as I'm aware, SE devs do check per-site metas for bug reports (i.e. anything tagged [meta-tag:bug]. It's just a matter of time before they show up ;-) See, e.g. https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/email-after-sending-a-community-team-message (it was Loong who posted this question).